Why this spatial join give me null values when I already tried every solution arcgis help can provide?
I have been trying to make a spatial join between a layer and an excel table, every time, every method I use always show null in the new values of the table. The layer contains rural information of a territory of my country, and, of course, spatial information, the table has information about some poblational indexes and I need to spatialize them through the join of the fields SECR_CCNCT and Codigo2
I already tried to:

Save the table as .CSV

Export the table and import it again

I checked multiple times if the data type of the two fields I want to join are the same, and they are (the field in the layer is text(11) and the field in the table is text(255))

I tried to do it in arcgis online

Re-make the excel


Just nothing works, I would really appreciate some help to solve this issue

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
